# how do you search Right/Left joins?

Tags: sql, join

I am having a problem searching multiple tables
,i have 2 tables

tblcourse

-courseid

-name

-status

tblenroll

-courseid(holds courseid from tblcourse)

-studentid

lets say a student has 1990 as student num and he registered to 2 courses in tblenrol

I want to get the name of the courses that 1990 has and the ones he aint subscribed to

the closest i get is a right outer join to tblcourses then i get the result i want, but once i attach a where clause it wont give me the rest of the courses that havent got his student number.

Any help!!

**EDIT (added from answer posted by op)**

Hey, thanks for reply. Ok I don't think that I explained it properly.

tblcourse will hold many courses
tblenroll holds many enrollments

So, imagine we have 6 courses. Student 1990 registers for 3 and student 1880 for 1 (one that 1990 didn't pick)

When we run this:

```
WHERE (tblenroll.studentid = 1990 or tblenroll.studentid is null)
```

or

```
where e.studentid is null or  e.studentid is not null and e.studentid = 1990
```

it will pick up 5 courses, 3 registered to 1990 and 2 NULLS. The sixth one is registered to 1880.

This query brings the right results but not for a specific student

```
SELECT
    tblenroll.studentid as stud,
    tblcourse.name,
    tblenroll.studentid,
    tblenroll.courseid,
    tblcourse.courseid,
FROM
    tblenroll
Right Join tblcourse ON tblenroll.courseid = tblcourse.courseid
```

With the above I will get

1880 - 1
1990 - 3
NULL - 2

confusing stuff!

Answer (score 2):

```
select tblcourse.name, e.studentid
from tblcourse c left join tblenroll e on c.courseid = e.courseid
where e.studentid is null or  e.studentid is not null and e.studentid = :id
```

it will result in

```
course1 1990
course2 NULL
course3 NULL
course4 1990
...
```

depending on your DB you can use a kind of IIF function to put either 1 or 0, true or false - whatever flag as second element

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to let the studentid be null as well as the actual id you're querying.

Try, for example:

```
SELECT tblenroll.studentid, tblcourse.courseid, tblcourse.name, tblcourse.status
FROM tblenroll RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblcourse ON tblenroll.courseid = tblcourse.courseid
WHERE (tblenroll.studentid = 1990 
or tblenroll.studentid is null) -- this allows the courses in which 1990 is not enrolled
```

Edit: I didn't quite think this through the first time.  The above query is my naieve approach and is probably returning the same results that the OP *doesn't* want.  The trick is not to use a where clause after the tables are joined, but rather to limit the rows from tblenroll that participate in the join.

I beleive this should work (I tested it with similar tables/structure on SQL Server 2005):

```
SELECT tblenroll.studentid, tblcourse.courseid, tblcourse.name, tblcourse.status
FROM tblenroll RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblcourse ON tblenroll.courseid = tblcourse.courseid
    AND tblenroll.studentid = 1990
```